# AWS Websockets API Gateway and existing devices

Tags: websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have a number of non-upgradable devices in the field that are currently talking HTTP and WS to an EC2 instance.

I'd like to separate the websockets and use the Websockets API Gateway, but my devices are using the same DNS name for both HTTP and WS communications (albeit different ports). So I would need to put something in front of the WS API Gateway to route the two types of connections.
Doesn't sound like a LB is an option, because it doesn't have API Gateway as a target.

Is there a good way?